# Django how to filter table with dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

I have created an app that collect all daily income. The model is the following:

```
class Income(models.Model):
        date=models.DateField('', default="GG/MM/YYYY")
        income=models.DecimalField()
```

I have created a simple template that contains the form and the data table with all data collected.

```
<form method="post">
<div class="row">
h5>Income data collection</h5>
<div class="row">
             <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                 {{form.income|as_crispy_field}}
             </div>
             <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                 {{form.date|as_crispy_field}}
             </div>
  </div>
        <table class="table" >           
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Income</th>
              <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {% for inc in income%}
              <tr>
                  <td>{{inc.income}}</td>
                  <td>{{inc.date}}</td>                  
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

In the views I have added the following filter:

```
income=Income.objects.filters(data__year='2020')
```

At this point, I have created another model that set the reference year as the following:

I have the following model

```
class Timing(models.Model):
    reference_year=models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, default="2020")
```

This model have a view with form that give to the client the possibility to register all reference year (2020, 2021 and so on). Now I want to link `reference_year` with `income` views.py. How? with a dropdown menu that cointains all reference_year filled. 
So for example if clients save in timing models a reference_year equal to 2020, in the dropdown the client could select it and the views dynamically update the filter.

Answer (score 0):

in your models.py add a one-to-one relation between those 2 models.

following program is given in django documentation you can use it as a refrence.

```
    from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```